# The policy over F-1 visa when the holder changes his academic program after the visa is expired

Tags: usa, visa, students

I heard that for some cases, the F-1 visa holder doesn't have to renew his visa if the visa is expired. But how about the following cases after the visa was expired?

- The holder transfers from a college to a college.
- The holder moves from an undergrad school to a grad school of different university.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A US visa is *only* for entry to the US. If the person does not need to enter the US, then they do not need a valid US visa. (That's also why US visas can only be gotten outside the US.) A US visa has no bearing on the person's status after entering the US.

A person who is already in the US in F-1 status can transfer to different schools as much as they want as long as they get an I-20 from the new school. They will remain in F-1 status. A visa has nothing to do with it.